# Python 2.7.3 : Sep argument showing error

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I am using sep argument in the Python 2.7.3, it is showing error

for example:-

```
      >>>print ("Hello","World",sep ="**")
           File "<stdin>", line 1
           print ("Hello","World",sep ="**")
                           ^
          SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 23):

In Python 2.x, unlike in Python 3.x, `print` is not a function, but a *statement* described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement). Basically it means that `print` is treated as a keyword (like `for`) and is not as powerful as the `print` function that you know from Python 3.x. In particular, it does not support the `sep` keyword argument.

You can make `print` behave similarly to Python 3.x by using the following import:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

If you prefer no to use this import, you can achieve the effect you wanted with:

```
print "**".join(["Hellow", "World"])
```

Comment: For the record, the error is that the statement is interpreted as “print the following: `("Hello","World",sep ="**”)`”. `("Hello","World",sep ="**”)` is not valid syntax — you can’t have keyword args in a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

You need to type this line first:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

To make `print` a function, and allow passing arguments like that.